# Get the method name and it's contained parameters by parsing the exception

Tags: java, exception

When I received an exception such as `IOException` or `RunTimeException`, I can only know the line number in the class.

First of my question. Is it possible to retrieve the method name through exception?
Second, is it possible to retrieve the method and the parameter of this method by line number?

p.s. I need to know the exact method name and its parameters, because I want to distinguish the overloading methods. To distinguish overloading methods, all that I know is to determine its parameters.

Comment: You can distinguish which overloaded method was called by the line number.  Unless you have more than one method declared on the same line (I don't suggest you do that)

Comment: Or the source code is compiled without debug information :-/

Comment: To Peter: yes, I can distinguish by the line number. But I want to know how to code to grab this information instead of manually looking or tracing.

Answer (score 6):

```
try{
//your code here}
catch(Exception e){
  for (StackTraceElement st : e.getStackTrace())
  {
    System.out.println("Class: " + st.getClassName() + " Method : " 
                      +  st.getMethodName() + " line : " + st.getLineNumber());  
   }
}
```

as you can see in the code above, you can get the stackTrace and loop over it to get all the method names and line numbers, refer to this for more info http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

Comment: Thanks for the code you provide. Though my question is to get the method and its parameter. I need both of them because when methods overloading, we have to judge the exact one by its parameters.

Comment: Can't you know that from the line number?

Comment: To Amjad Masad:
  How do you distinguish the overloading methods by line number?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stacktrace you can know in which line the error occurred.

When using an overriden method you get the exact class name, source file and line number, you just have to [know how to read it.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)

From that page:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
         at MyClass.mash(MyClass.java:9)  //<--- HERE!!!!
         at MyClass.crunch(MyClass.java:6)
         at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:3)
```

This says, the problem occurred in `line 9` of file `MyClass.java` in the method `mash`, which was in turn invoked by the method `crunch` at l`ine 6` of the same file which was invoked by  `main` in `line 3` of the same file.

Heres the source code:

```
 class MyClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         crunch(null); // line 3
     }
     static void crunch(int[] a) {
         mash(a); // line 6 
     }
     static void mash(int[] b) {
         System.out.println(b[0]);//line 9, method mash.
     }
 }
```

Basically you just have to ... well  read it!

Stacktraces are a bit hard to grasp the first time, but later they become a very powerful tool.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, OscarRyz.
My concern is not about the overriden methods, but the Overloading methods.
For example:
public void methodA(int a);
public void methodA(bool a);

Comment: Of course, we can read the source code by given information. What I really want to do is to retrieve to method automatically, using code to capture the method. Do you have any idea to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It should work the same for overloaded methods. It is not possible to capture the method arguments from the stacktrace. What you could do is to provide that information before throwing the exception which I think is not feasible.  What are you going to do with that information anyway?  I'm curious

Comment: My idea is to collect the annotation from the thrown exception methods. If the methods is not overloading, I can at least know the method name. But if there are overloading methods, I can't tell which one of method throwing the exceptions. All that I can get is line number and class name which we discussed below.
Do you have any better idea, OscarRyz? Any way, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

pass it the exception and it will print the parameter types of the methods along with the exception

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]  args)
    {
        new Main().run();
    }
    public void run(){
        try
        {
            new Car().run(60, "Casino");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            detailedException(e);
        }
        try
        {
            new Engine().run(10);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            detailedException(e);
        }
    }
    public void detailedException(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(e.getClass().getName()).append(" \"").append(e.getMessage()).append("\"\n");
            for (var trace: e.getStackTrace())
            {
                buffer.append("\tat ").append(trace.getClassName()).append(".").append(trace.getMethodName()).append("(").append(trace.getFileName()).append(":").append(trace.getLineNumber()).append(")[");
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(trace.getClassName());
                ArrayList<Method> methods = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clazz.getMethods()));
                methods.removeIf(m -> !m.getName().equals(trace.getMethodName()));
                Method method = methods.get(0);
                for (var param: method.getParameters())
                {
                    buffer.append(param.getName()).append(":").append(param.getParameterizedType().getTypeName()).append(", ");
                }
                buffer.append("]->").append(method.getGenericReturnType().getTypeName()).append("\n");
            }
            System.err.println(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception parseFailed){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class Car extends Engine
{
    public void run(int when, String where) throws Exception 
    {
        super.run(25);
    }
}
class Engine
{
    public String run(int For) throws Exception 
    {
        throw new Exception("need more fuel");
    }
}
```